# jQuery replace one class with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery and I'm changing styles in it but I've heard that the correct way to do it is to create a separate style and just replace classes with jQuery. Can you explain me how to do it correctly:

```
$('.corpo_buttons_asia').click(function() {           
    $('.info').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.info2').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).css('z-index', '20');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(23,55,94)');
    $(this).css('color', '#FFF');
    $('.corpo_buttons_global').css('background-color', 'rgb(197,197,197)');
    $('.corpo_buttons_global').css('color', '#383838');         
}); 

$('.corpo_buttons_global').click(function() { 
    $('.info').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.info2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(23,55,94)');
    $(this).css('color', '#FFF');
    $('.corpo_buttons_asia').css('z-index', '2');
    $('.corpo_buttons_asia').css('background-color', 'rgb(197,197,197)');
    $('.corpo_buttons_asia').css('color', '#383838');
});
```

So instead of using *.css()* all the time I can create another class and just replace it with jQuery.

Comment: use addClass() method in jquery to assign different css class on the go

Answer (score 192, accepted):

**To do this efficiently using jQuery, you can chain it like so:**

```
$('.theClassThatsThereNow').addClass('newClassWithYourStyles').removeClass('theClassThatsTherenow');
```

For simplicities sake, you can also do it step by step like so (note assigning the jquery object to a var isnt necessary, but it feels safer in case you accidentally remove the class you're targeting before adding the new class and are directly accessing the dom node via its jquery selector like `$('.theClassThatsThereNow')`):

```
var el = $('.theClassThatsThereNow');
el.addClass('newClassWithYourStyles');
el.removeClass('theClassThatsThereNow');
```

**Also (since there is a js tag), if you wanted to do it in vanilla js:**

For modern browsers ([See this to see which browsers I'm calling modern](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp))

(assuming one element with class `theClassThatsThereNow`)

```
var el = document.querySelector('.theClassThatsThereNow');
el.classList.remove('theClassThatsThereNow');
el.classList.add('newClassWithYourStyleRules');
```

Or older browsers:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('theClassThatsThereNow');
el.className = el.className.replace(/\s*theClassThatsThereNow\s*/, ' newClassWithYourStyleRules ');
```

Comment: is switchClass not a thing?

Comment: @Jwan622 if youre using jquery ui it is.  this question was about regular jquery.

Comment: Good stuff. We can also use the toggleClass in chain to toggle multiple class e.g. 
$(this).toggleClass("btn-wishlist_inactive").toggleClass("btn-wishlist_active");
    $('.btn-wishlist__icon').toggleClass("btn-wishlist__icon-plus").toggleClass("btn-wishlist__icon-toplay")

Comment: If you're OK to use vanilla JS, then do `el.classList.replace('foo', 'bar')`.

Answer (score 21):

You may use this simple plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.replaceClass = function (pFromClass, pToClass) {
        return this.removeClass(pFromClass).addClass(pToClass);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Usage:

```
$('.divFoo').replaceClass('colored','blackAndWhite');
```

Before:

```
<div class="divFoo colored"></div>
```

After:

```
<div class="divFoo blackAndWhite"></div>
```

Note: you may use various space separated classes.

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes when you have multiple classes and you really need to **overwrite** all of them, it's easiest to use jQuery's [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to overwrite the `class` attribute:

```
$('#myElement').attr('class', 'new-class1 new-class2 new-class3');
```

Comment: I think this is the most efficient way to replace the class?

Comment: Definitely better than using removeClass + addClass!

Answer (score 11):

Starting with the HTML fragment:

```
<div class='helpTop ...
```

use the javaScript fragment:

```
$(...).toggleClass('helpTop').toggleClass('helpBottom');
```

Comment: You could just write `$(...).toggleClass("helpTop helpBottom");`

Comment: You may drop jQuery. Use: myNode.classList.toggle(... 
or myNode.classList.toggle('helpTop', condition); myNode.classList.toggle('helpBottom', !condition); Even better: myNode.classList.toggle('helpTop', !myNode.classList.toggle('helpBottom', condition));

Answer (score 8):

In jquery to replace a class with another you can use **jqueryUI SwitchClass** option

```
 $("#YourID").switchClass("old-class-here", "new-class-here");
```

Comment: This is a jQueryUI functionality: https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.removeClass` and `.addClass`. More in http://api.jquery.com.

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to create a class with CSS -

```
.greenclass {color:green;}
```

Then you could add that to elements with

```
$('selector').addClass("greenclass");
```

and remove it with -

```
$('selector').removeClass("greenclass");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery methods `.hasClass()`, `.addClass()`, and `.removeClass()` to manipulate which classes are applied to your elements. Just define different classes and add/remove them as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class in your CSS file:

```
.active {
  z-index: 20;
  background: rgb(23,55,94)
  color: #fff;
}
```

Then in your jQuery

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 2):

you could have both of them use a "corpo_button" class, or something like that, and then in `$(".corpo_button").click(...)` just call `$(this).toggleClass("corpo_buttons_asia corpo_buttons_global");`

Comment: Those might not be the actual classes you wanted to add/remove, now that I looked at your example again. Still though, toggleClass is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.fn.replaceClass = function(sSearch, sReplace) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var s = (' ' + this.className + ' ').replace(
            ' ' + sSearch.trim() + ' ',
            ' ' + sReplace.trim() + ' '
        );
        this.className = s.substr(1, s.length - 2);
    });
};
```

### EDIT

This is my solution to replace one class with another (the jQuery way). Actually the other answers **don't replace one class with another** but **add one class and remove another** which technically is not the same at all.

Here is an example:

Markup before: `<br class="el search-replace"><br class="el dont-search-replace">`
js: `jQuery('.el').remove('search-replace').add('replaced')`
Markup after: `<br class="el replaced"><br class="el dont-search-replace replaced">`

---

**With my solution**

js: `jQuery('.el').replaceClass('search-replace', 'replaced')`
Markup after: `<br class="el replaced"><br class="el dont-search-replace">`

---

Imagine a string replace function in whatever language:

Search: "search-replace"
Replace: "replaced"
Subject: "dont-search-replace"
Result: "dont-search-replace"
Result (**wrong** but actually what the other solutions produce): "dont-search-replace replaced"

---

**PS**
If it's for sure that the class to add is not present and the class to remove is present for sure the most simple jQuery solution would be: 
`jQuery('el').toggleClass('is-present-will-be-removed is-not-present-will-be-added')`

**PPS** I'm totally aware that if your selector equals the class to remove the other solutions would work just fine `jQuery('.search-replace').removeClass('search-replace').addClass('whatever')`.
But sometimes you work with more arbitrary collections.

Comment: Please explain a bit how your answer help to solve the question

Comment: @Axel can you help me replace class "owl-carousel-block2" with "owl-carousel"  - https://bryanbowers.me/seven/?q=node/5     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404871/owl-carousel-not-inline

Comment: @sloga do you still need my advice. sry beeing kinda late to the party!

Answer (score 1):

I have used swap div to swap my video of self in thumbnail to main-video and vise versa.

I think this will help you to make a toggle between two div class.

```
numberId=0
function swapVideo(){
  numberId++;
 console.log(numberId)
  if(numberId % 2 ==0){
  $('#self-video').attr('class', 'main-video');
    $('#trainer-video').attr('class', 'thumb-video');
  }else{
     $('#self-video').attr('class', 'thumb-video');
         $('#trainer-video').attr('class', 'main-video');
  }
}
```

**numberId%2==0** help to keep track and perform a operation to make this toggle.