# How to switch class in Jquery randomly?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to at first add a class to a div and then replace it using a randomly chosen class in Jquery.

On initial load, my html looks like this:

```
<div class="portfolio-image boomer"></div>
```

After 5 seconds, I'd like one of a list of 4 classes to replace boomer, i.e.

```
<div class="portfolio-image red"></div>
```

then in another 5 seconds, replace the class added in the previous step to a new one, i.e.

```
<div class="portfolio-image green"></div>
```

My random classes are red, green, blue, gold.

my jQuery works up to the point where it adds the random class at the end but it keeps adding on each step instead of replacing, so I am getting:

```
<div class="portfolio-image boomer green"></div>
```

and then

```
<div class="portfolio-image boomer green red"></div>
```

etc. So, my problems are how to remove the initial class "boomer" with the first random class and then keep replacing that random class on each step? Without knowing what the last randomly added class to the specific element was, how can I use switchClass or removeClass? Or am I approaching this completely backwards?

my javascript:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    animateTheBoxes();
});
function animateTheBoxes() {
  var classes = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'gold'];
        jQuery(".portfolio-image").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
    setTimeout(animateTheBoxes, 5000);
}
```

Many thanks for any consideration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery replace one class with another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249785/jquery-replace-one-class-with-another)

Comment: Possible duplicate of a duplicate -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553036/random-color-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (since it doesn't require you to maintain any state as to what the *current* colour is);

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    animateTheBoxes();
});

function animateTheBoxes() {
    var classes = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'gold'];

    jQuery(".portfolio-image").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('boomer ' + classes.join(' ')).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });

    setTimeout(animateTheBoxes, 5000);
}
```

For more info, see [the docs for `removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass).

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most performant solution, but you could just remove all classes, and then add the "portfolio-image" class and then the randomly selected one.  jQuery.removeClass() with no parameters will remove all classes.  So something like this might work.

```
jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('portfolio-image ' + classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('class', 'portfolio-image ' + classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)])` would be more appropriate then...

Comment: Yeah, you're right Wouter.  I don't know enough about the guts of jQuery to know how much work the browser is actually doing between removeClass() and addClass().  If it's causing a paint or something like that between those two calls, it would be definitely better to handle it in one action.