# Replace a part of the class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a music player button. The button has a 'play' icon when the muisc is not playing and switch to a 'music' icon when the music is playing. The icon I am using is "Font Awesome".

```
<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
// This is a play icon
<i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i>
// This is a music icon
```

So all I need is to replace a part of the class name(replace play to music), right? It seems a little bit hard to accomplish. I am wondering whether this is a good way to implement the button or not.(I'am still working hard on the code right now...) I'll be appreciate if you give me some advice!!

Comment: Hmm.  This question is going to get down-voted really hard.  But before that happens, here's a related question that might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249785/jquery-replace-one-class-with-another. Good luck!

Comment: `$(".fa-play").toggleClass("fa-play fa-music")` - that is, don't think of it as replacing part of a class's name, think of it as removing one class and adding another.

Comment: @nnnnnn Wouldn't the `$('.fa-play')` be gone on first toggle and the selector wouldn't be valid because there's only `.fa-music`?

Comment: @zer00ne - well the question didn't mention changing it *back*, and my comment was intended more as a hint then as a complete solution, so... Anyway, if there is only one such element on the page then `$(".fa").toggleClass("fa-play fa-music")` would switch in either direction; if there are multiple elements then you couldn't use a string selector, you'd want to use `this` or some other sort of DOM navigation from an event handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn I see, ok

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks a lot! Finally figure it out!

Answer (score 4):

**JavaScript** / Example 1

Use [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) on one `<i>`

```js
var fa = document.querySelector('i');

fa.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('fa-play');
  this.classList.toggle('fa-music');
}, false);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**jQuery** / Example 2

Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) on one `<i>` (this is effective for multiple `<i>` with dual class as well)

```js
$('.fa-play, .fa-music').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-play fa-music');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>
<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>
<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toggleClass(sender) {
  $(sender).toggleClass('fa-play fa-music')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></i>
```

Comment: Why not just `$('.fa').toggleClass('fa-play fa-music')`? You never have to use an inline attribute event handler (ie `onclick`) when you use jQuery.

Comment: .fa could be use for other purpose. I dont think he wants to toggle all (.fa) classes on click

Comment: True, if I may, sir, I can edit your question to show an efficient version in jQuery.